# How to create complex date constraint in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I'm developing java application with JPA. In the application I have Rooms and Reservations :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RESERVATIONS")
public class Reservation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Room room;
    private LocalDate checkInDate;
    private LocalDate checkOutDate;

    //getters setters
}
```

I want to validate that the room cannot be booked twice for the same period.

Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: You'll need to write code. That's business logic. Execute a query checking if the room is already checked in that period before creating the reservation.

Comment: Yes I thought soo but does this solution would be thread safe if I put the both queries in one transaction?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. But two reservations of the same room in such a short timespan is very unlikely, and you could add other ways to avoid that situation (like, for example, a regular check of the validity of each room, and compensating measures, or locks).

Comment: short transaction on finalisation (in business level: operator decision to finalise) seems good idea, with lock on Room. JPA 2.0 has good one